# How can a cube project be deployed to a remote server in a different domain?

Tags: ssas

I have severe trouble deploying a cube project from a development machine to a SSAS-server.

No matter, what I try, a connection ›cannot be made‹, although everything seems to be fine.

This is the situation:

**Server**:
   DNS: db.mydomain.at
   Windows-Name: DB

Installed Software:
   Windows Server 2019 Standard; standalone
   MS SQL Server 2019 DevEd

*Running* Services:
   MSSQL:
      Logins:
         DB\test (integrated sec., able to connect in Mgmt Studio locally & remote)
         Db-User DB\test (for login DB\test)
   SSAS:
      Login:
         DB\test (integr. sec, able to connect in Mgmt Studio locally & remote)
   SQLBrowser running
   SQLAgent running

Firewall: Port 2383 open

OS-account DB\test is member of SQLServerMSASUser$DB$MSSQLServer
and of SSAS-Admin (so he can create databases)

**Client**:
   no DNS-Name
   Windows-Name: DEV

Installed software:
   Win 10
   VS 2019 community
   MSDT AS
   SSMS

User: DEV\test (with same password as DB\test)

Data Source:
   I tried with servers: db.mydomain.at, db & DB.
   (Ping works for all 4.)

I tried all 4 ›impersonations‹:
   Errors differ, but invariably lead to ›a connection cannot be made‹,
   although a database has been created on the OLAP-server!

Creating and transferring an xmla-file (as indicated in Q1215053) is not feasible, the solution has to be online.

Any hint, what I'm missing, would be highly appreciated!

Add: Further experiments yielded the following:

I played around with the ›impersonation‹ (the credentials, the OLAP-server uses to fetch data from the OLTP-server – as I understand it).

Specific Windows user name: DB\test: ›Login is from untrusted domain‹.
test: ›Login is from untrusted domain‹.

Service account: ›Login failed for NT AUTHORITY\ANONYMOUS LOGON‹
(Tried with NT Service\MSSQLServerOLAPService and LocalSystem as logon accounts for SSAS.)

Credentials of current user: ›ImpersonationMode that is not supported‹

Inherited: ›Login failed for NT AUTHORITY\ANONYMOUS LOGON‹

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem was a misconfigured server; solution was to fully qualify the server's computer name.

The server had of course a ›Computer name‹ (›db‹, NetBIOS name ›DB‹), but the ›full computer name‹ also was ›db‹ and the DNS suffix was missing. I added a ›Primary DNS suffix for the computer‹: ›mydomain.at‹ and the project happily deployed.